# Not able to pass array as argument inside find method

Tags: php, mongodb, php-7, php-mongodb

I have this code:

```
require_once __DIR__ . "/vendor/autoload.php";

$collection = (new MongoDB\Client)->google_api->threadContents;

$document = $collection->find(["messages.payload.headers.value"=>"kruno@ulix.com"]);
echo "<pre>";
var_dump($document["id"]);
```

I am trying to search for all objects that match specific criteria. This works exactly as I wanted when I used `findOne` method, but when I use find method to find all of the objects rather than just one I get next error:

> Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Cannot use object of type
>   MongoDB\Driver\Cursor as array in...

Comment: Your find statement will return a cursor which will be stored in the $document var, what are you doing next? show us the entire code.

Comment: @Vincent Now I updated the question, this is full code.

Comment: @Vincent I actually chained toArray method and the line looks like this now: `$document = $collection->find(["messages.payload.headers.value"=>"kruno@ulix.com"])->toArray();` but it really ate all the RAM

Comment: Yes that's valid, try iterating through using foreach, see if that works, if toArray() is using up your memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP's MongoDB\Driver\Cursor implements Traversable class so you can Iterate through the results using the foreach loop but cannot directly access it like an Array with the [] statement.
Do this,

```
foreach($document as $fields){
  print_r($fields);
}
```

Comment: This method is killing a lot of RAM too. It took 9 GB for ~200 mails